# javascript añadir y remover clase con onclick en boton bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente boton y deseo que haga la siguiente funcion, al presionarlo cambie el texto a "Procesando" y se deshabilite, luego de unos segundos vuelva a cambiar el texto y habilitarse. Pero, no logro que funcione del todo necesito ayuda. Si es posible que el boton al presionarlo tenga un icono de cargando y al volver al principal tenga el check seria super

```js
function YosmarBotonxD(){
            
        $("#actualizar_datos").addClass("disabled");
        $("#actualizar_datos").text("Procesando...");
        //se activa la función Bloquear() luego de 4 segundos
        setTimeout(Bloquear,4000);    
    }
    function Bloquear(){
        $("#actualizar_datos").removeClass("disabled");
        $("#actualizar_datos").text("Actualizar personal");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="actualizar_datos" onclick="YosmarBotonxD()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Actualizar personal</button>
```

Comment: tienes el jquery importado?, por que da error por eso.

Comment: No tengo idea amigo, en mi sitio si me corre, pero solo se cambia el texto y deshabilita más nada.

Comment: haz el snnipet funcional para ver cual es resultado de tu código , pon el cdn por favor.

Comment: ahora que está funcional tu código, dice que `Mensaje` no está definido.

Comment: listo ahora ya carga el mensaje

Comment: Creo que el unico error es, que no me lo deshabilita y habilita

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El tema de los botones disabled no se gestiona por clase, podrías hacerlo con las propiedades oportunas de CSS, pero para eso el elemento `button` tiene un atributo propio, `disabled`.

En este fragmento no voy a quitar el proceso de añadir y quitar clase que has definido anteriormente, pero sí que incluyo la gestión del atributo disabled del botón que mencionas. Pruébalo a ver si te sirve.

```js
function YosmarBotonxD(){            
    $("#actualizar_datos").addClass("disabled");
    $("#actualizar_datos").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#actualizar_datos").text("Procesando...");
    //se activa la función Bloquear() luego de 4 segundos
    setTimeout(Bloquear,4000);    
}

function Bloquear(){
    $("#actualizar_datos").removeClass("disabled");
    $("#actualizar_datos").prop("disabled", false)
    $("#actualizar_datos").text("Actualizar personal");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="actualizar_datos" onclick="YosmarBotonxD()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Actualizar personal</button>
```

Comment: Si se deshabilita, peeero, no me valida el formulario ni me hace el submit :S

Comment: a esta linea `$("#actualizar_datos").attr("disabled", "disabled");` le quite el segundo `disabled` y ahora si me va perfecto. Muchas gracias

Comment: Otra cosa, si se deshabilita pero, mientras tiene esa class permite volver a presionarlo, y desearia que no lo permitiera como seria?

Comment: He editado el snippet, en lugar de hacerlo por atributos, es mejor hacerlo por propiedades, prueba con eso a ver si se soluciona tanto el problema del formulario como el problema del click y me dices :D